# Oracle RegExp_Substr not able to escape comma present between quotes

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle11g

I have a JSON File, as shown below.

```
"orderingCustomer":{
   "@class":"com.worldwide.sector",
   "option":"K",
   "addressLine1":"DYNAMIC OFFICE, STREET 2",
   "addressLine2":null,
   "addressLine3":null,
   "partyId":null,
   "partyName":"DYNAMIC LTD",
   "partyBic":null,
   "accountNumber":null
   }
```

My Query does parsing of this JSON, and returns rows based on Comma(,) as delimiter.

```
SELECT CAST( TRIM( REGEXP_SUBSTR( ( SELECT REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( SWIFT_DATA, 32000 ), '["]orderingCustomer["]:{[^}]+' ), '"orderingCustomer":"', '' )
                                       FROM TXN_SWIFT
                                      WHERE ID_TXN_SWIFT = 123 ),
                                   '[^,]+',
                                   1,
                                   3 ) ) AS VARCHAR2( 320 ) )
            TRANSTYPE
  FROM TXN_SWIFT_OUT_MSG
 WHERE MESSAGE_UUID = 12345;
```

This query works fine, and gives me row-wise results for each keyword based on delimiter (comma). But I have a problem when I search for "addressLine1", where the results is shown as

```
"addressLine1":"DYNAMIC OFFICE
```

instead of

```
"addressLine1":"DYNAMIC OFFICE, STREET 2"
```

I have tried changing the regular expression to the regex shown

```
[,(?=(?:\[^"\]*"\[^"\]*")*\[^"\]*$)][1]
```

But still I am unable to get the data required as shown above, even after replacing the regex from `[^,]+` to `,(?=(?:\[^"\]*"\[^"\]*")*\[^"\]*$)`

I no longer even get the values. Please suggest, what could be with my query.
(Using 11g version)

Answer (score 0):

Exploit the json syntax:

```
"[^"]+":("[^"]+"|null)
```

Basically this mirrors the syntax for representing a single property in json. Supported types are strings and null.

[Test it](https://regex101.com/r/W2obbU/3) at regex101.

***Caveat***

This regex does not handle the case of escaped double quotes inside strings. The following modification addresses this issue:

```
"[^:]+?:("([^\\"]+(\\.)*)+"|null|true|false)
```

Basically, this pattern interprets a string delimited by double quotes as a sequence of strings without `\` or `"` separated by sequences of escaped characters. The construct includs the case that there are no such escaped characters. (The additional literals cover boolean attributes).

[Test it](https://regex101.com/r/W2obbU/4) at regex101.

***Note***

Note that neither arrays nor objects as property values are supported, but as the original pattern obviously does not account for them either, this does not seem to be part of your requirements.
    Note that if it would, regex matching get nasty quickly since you'll have to cater for recursion in your pattern ( which i am not even sure whether oracle's  regex engine would support ).

Comment: Thanks a lot @collapsar. Worked like charm